# Re-sizing Image Using CDC

Tags: c++, frames, cdc, video-editing, lpstr

I am trying to write a component for my program to re-size image frames from a video. The current code is called, which takes the `CDC` from the current frame.

```
void showImageFrame(LPSTR info)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER * pInfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER *)info;
    CDC* pDC=pWnd=GetDlgItem(IDCFrame)->GetDC();
    CRect rect;
    pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect);
    SetDIBitsToDevice(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), 0, 0, 0, pInfo->biHeight, info + *(LPDWORD)info, (LPBITMAPINFO) pInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    pDC->StretchBlt(0,0,200,200,pDC,0,0,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),SRCCOPY);
}
```

The `StretchBlt` does re-size the image displayed at the current frame, but it retains the larger image from the `SetDIBitsToDevice`. Is there any way to remove the image of the `SetDIBitsToDevice`, or do this in a more efficient way? I am trying to re-size the image to 200x200.

Using the current code above, I get the following output.
[image]

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXRZ.png

Comment: Is your intention to resize the image and show it in the window (frame) same as the source window (frame)?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to re-size the image and display it within the same frame. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to show code in these comments. sorry for the untidiness

Answer (score 0):

One quick way. Create a blank (white) image and stretch it over the original image, then StretchBlt your resized image.

Comment: Do you know of any way to accomplish it without using any other images/videos?

Comment: ' HBITMAP CScene::saveDCtoBuffer(HDC hdc, HINSTANCE hInst) { HBITMAP tBitmap; HDC hTargetDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); tBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,width,height-TOOLBARHEIGHT-STATUSBARHEIGHT); SelectObject(hTargetDC,tBitmap); BitBlt(hTargetDC, 0, 0, width, height-TOOLBARHEIGHT-STATUSBARHEIGHT, hdc, 0, TOOLBARHEIGHT, SRCCOPY); DeleteDC(hTargetDC); return tBitmap; } ' This is not MFC, but is should help you. Once you have the new image use "Rectangle" and draw a white polygon over the original image, then bitblt the image as copied with the function.